# Check if Checkbox is selected previosly?

Tags: php, mysql, session, checkbox

if checkbox is selected previously then it must be invisible.
it have to work if user logout and login next time too.
I am using php and mysql & there is no specific table for sessions

Answer (score 0):

Assign an index to each checkbox, starting from 0.

If your number of checkboxes is small, you can add a column to users. The type of that column should be `tinyint` if you have 8 or fewer, `smallint` if you have 16 or fewer, `midiumint` if you have 24 or fewer, `int` if you have 32 or fewer, `bigint` if you have 64 or fewer. Let it initially be 0. Each time a checkbox is checked, set the corresponding bit to 1.

If the number of checkboxes is large and many of them are likely to get checked, you can use binary instead of integer types.

If the number of checkboxes is large and it is not likely that many of them get checked, you can add a table listing which user has checked which checkboxes. Each time a user checkes a checkbox, add a row to that table that has the user and the checkbox.